# Invoke an Omni-Channel Flow Route to Non-Real Time Objects Change Owner

Tags: skills-based-routing

I am trying to work out the value of Invoke an [Omni-Channel Flow to Route Non-Real Time Objects](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.omnichannel_use_flow_to_route.htm&type=5)

> To route non-real-time objects, such as cases, leads, and custom
> objects, define the routing logic in an Omni-Channel flow, and then
> invoke the flow from a parent flow based on your business rules. For
> example, to trigger the flow to run when cases are created, add it as
> a subflow in a record-triggered flow.

I've created Skills, a Service Channel, a Routing Configuration, Presence Configurations, etc.

**I'm trying to figure out what the expected result?** I see the record in the Omni-Channel Router component when I log in as one of my users - **does Omni-Channel Skills-based routing ONLY add the component there and then do users need to accept it before ownership is transferred?**

I've created an Omni-Channel Flow, and a Record Triggered Flow to invoke it.
[image: Omni-Channel Flow]